# How to check if the dictionary is empty or not in robot framework using python

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I tried to check the given dictionary is empty or not in robot framework but it is giving an error saying syntax error. Here is the following example of how I compared it:

Run Keyword If  '${source_list_data}'=='[]' FAIL and the error which i got is:

Evaluating expression ''[{'data':'value'}]'=='[]'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Comment: 1. First calculate length of your list by Get Length keyword 2. Run simple if condition to take action written below ->> [code written in RIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uikqb.png)

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax works for me. Strange it does not work for you.

Here is another way to achieve it using [Get Length](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Length):

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
dict_empty
    ${source_list_data} =  create dictionary
    ${length} =  Get Length  ${source_list_data}
    Run Keyword If  ${length} == 0  log to console  Empty Dict
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if dictionary is empty in robot framework, automatic dictionary variable "&{EMPTY}" can be used:

```
Run Keyword if  ${dict} == &{EMPTY}  'Some Action Keyword'
```